# Search for word under cursor and invoke function on key press VimScript

Tags: vim

Hi I am currently trying to reformat python 2 code that was written using camelCase style variables and I need to convert them to snake_case.

I've written two small vimscript functions to aid in doing so. I would like to this one step further. I would like to on a single keystroke to search for the word under my cursor, and invoke my function `FindAndReplace` which will take the current search term and do the processing as opposed to me having to manually type in the search term using `input`.

```
function! SplitDelim(expr, pat)
    let result = []
    let expr = a:expr
    while 1
        let [w, s, e] = matchstrpos(expr, a:pat)
        if s == -1
            break
        endif
        call add(result, s ? expr[:s-1] : '')
        call add(result, join(['', tolower(w)], '_'))
        let expr = expr[e:]
    endwhile
    call add(result, expr)
    return join(result, '')
endfunction
function! FindAndReplace()
    " get current cursor position to keep screen constant
    let cur_cursor_pos = getpos('.')
    call inputsave()
    let g:search_term = input("Enter search term: ")
    call inputrestore()
    execute '%s' . '/' . g:search_term . '/' . SplitDelim(g:search_term, '[A-Z]') . '/'
    " set cursor back to where it was at start of invocation from execing s/
    call setpos('.', cur_cursor_pos)
endfunction
```

Examples

The contents of some file

```
fooBarBaz
```

invoking the function

`call FindAndReplace()`

pass search term through `input`

`fooBarBaz`

resultant file now reads

`foo_bar_baz`.

---

What I want

Open some file whose content is

`fooBarBaz` (place cursor over word)

press ctrl-q and the contents of the file becomes

`foo_bar_baz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've determined the solution to my question.

`expand('<cword>')` will return the current word under your cursor. The keybinding was a simple `nnoremap`.

Full solution

```
function! SplitDelim(expr, pat)
    let result = []
    let expr = a:expr
    while 1
        let [w, s, e] = matchstrpos(expr, a:pat)
        if s == -1
            break
        endif
        call add(result, s ? expr[:s-1] : '')
        call add(result, join(['', tolower(w)], '_'))
        let expr = expr[e:]
    endwhile
    call add(result, expr)
    return join(result, '')
endfunction

function! FindAndReplace()
    " get current cursor position to keep screen constant
    let cur_cursor_pos = getpos('.')
    let search_term = expand('<cword>')
    execute '%s' . '/' . search_term . '/' . SplitDelim(search_term, '[A-Z]') . '/'
    " set cursor back to where it was at start of invocation from execing s/
    call setpos('.', cur_cursor_pos)
endfunction

nnoremap <C-Q> :call FindAndReplace()<CR>
```

Comment: FWIW, `g:search_term` is only used in `FindAndReplace()` so it doesn't really need the `g:` prefix.